# How can I let someone just view my screen and not take control with a Mac 10.5 using VNC?

Tags: vnc

How can I let someone just view my screen and not take control with a Mac 10.5 using [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in Remote Management option in Sharing instead of Screen Sharing. That gives you more control over your options and you can uncheck the option to allow control of mouse and keyboard.

I should add that if you are connecting with a VNC client instead of ARD or ScreenSharing then the above won't work, but you can use Vine Server which will give you the option to have a view only mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could use join.me its a screen sharing this that can let people see your screen, but you have to sign up and download the join.me then you give the person the link to the page and they can see your screen if you allow them too.

The website is: www.join.me

Comment: The question was about using VNC to allow screen viewings.

Answer (score 0):

UltraVNC has the option to set 2 passwords, one for view+control and one for just view. Since most VNC versions are very similar, I would suppose that a similar option exists in other VNC flavours. Then just give out the view-only password.